# Express/Connect: is it possible to use the static middleware several times?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm using Express and I have my static files at a specific path and I serve them through static() middleware like that:

```
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I also use bower and used to configure a .bowerrc file to install stuff in that static used path.

I was wondering if I could not redefine a second static middleware like that:

```
app.use('/bower', express.static('/bower_components'));
```

So I get rid of my .bowerrc file.

But it's not working.  Is this sort of thing possible or am I completely misleading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can do that.  If the first argument to `use` is a string, you're [*mounting*](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) the middleware to a specific URL path.

It's probably not working because you're specifying an absolute path for the static middleware – did you really mean `bower_components` under the root directory `/`?

Comment: Yes I wanted to have the root directory of my project because that's where bower is installing his stuff by default

Comment: THat's kinda the issue thought because `app.use('/bower', express.static(__dirname + '/../bower_components'))` works fine

Comment: Right: the first argument to `use` is a URL pathname; only requests whose path starts with that string are passed through the middleware.  The string you pass to `express.static` is a **filesystem path**.  It has nothing to do with URLs; it is the folder you want the middleware to serve.  So when you say `express.static('/foo')`, you're asking the middleware to serve the files contained in a folder named `foo` under the root directory of the *server's filesystem* (not just your project folder).

Comment: @plus- Try running `ls /bower_components` in a terminal. You'll see that the directory doesn't exist. That's what you're telling `express.static` to use when you do `express.static('/bower_components')`.

Comment: Got that, I thought the second arg was a path resolved against the current execution path on the fs. Thanks josh

Comment: @plus-: You *can* use relative paths (they're resolved relative to the process's [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is not necessarily your project folder), but `/foo` is an *absolute* path.  You *could* do `../bower_components` -- that is a relative path -- but using `__dirname` is better because it will always be your project folder, not whatever the process working directory happens to be.

Comment: Yup that was a big mistake with that absolute path. that's how I could have wrote it from the beginning: `app.use('/bower', express.static('bower_components'));` as I don't plan to have a separate working directory

Comment: @plus-: The reason you shouldn't rely on working directory is that it is entirely dependent on *how* you start your app.  IE, if run from a shell like this: `~ $ node /var/my/app.js`, the working directory will be your home folder rather than the app's folder.  Depending on how you daemonize your app in production, the working directory could end up being a number of things.  That's why it's a good idea to be safe and use `__dirname + '/../foo'`.